How to install Nsight DL design
I seek guidance regarding the utilization of Nsight DL Designer on Linux. Despite successfully downloading the application, I encountered difficulties in executing it. Upon downloading the provided .run file, I performed the requisite steps of granting executable permissions using 'chmod +x' and subsequently executing it with './'. However, upon completion of this process, the application did not manifest itself, and subsequent attempts to execute './' merely resulted in the extraction process recurring.
I would appreciate assistance in resolving this matter. Thank you?

What do you mean by "However, upon completion of this process, the application did not manifest itself"? Is there any error message during installation? Can you find the executable for the Deep Learning Designer?

Installation was fine, when done i havent seen the application ( but check the folder was ok), if i redo the step ./nsightDLdesigner.run it will re-extract
